# Работа с Notification и Alarm Manager

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы уведомление приходило в заданное время (приложение типа напоминалки) у меня уведомление приходит сразу же, не обращая внимание на заданное время(10 API).

```
public class NotificationService extends Service{
    NotificationManager nm;
    Notification notif;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        sendNotif(intent);
        stopService(intent);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    void sendNotif(Intent mIntent) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        String movie_title = mIntent.getStringExtra("curmovie");
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTIF_MOVIE, movie_title);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 42);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplication().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_large))
                .setTicker("Check your movies")
                .setWhen(calendar.getTimeInMillis())
                .setContentTitle("Time for watching!")
                .setContentText(movie_title)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        notif = builder.build();
        notif.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.kos.checkmovies/" + R.raw.notif_sound);
        long[] vibrate = new long[]{1000,200,100,500};
        notif.vibrate = vibrate;
        nm.notify(1,notif);
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте удостовериться, что установленное время не меньше текущего.

Answer (score 1):

В продолжение сказанного Юрием в комментах, покажу код реализации:

```
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20); // это вроде нужно чтоб формат 24-часовой был
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 42);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Date today = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); // находим текущее время
    Log.e("calendar sets on :",""+calendar.getTime()); //лог установленного тобой времени

    if (calendar.getTime().before(today)) 
    { //если твоё время меньше текущего времени, то
       calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);// прибавляем время к твоему календарю
    }// у меня прибавляется 1 день недели, ты можешь добавить вместо DAY_OF_WEEK свой тип и значение
```